# Help with dropping voltage on 1000w dc power

Tags: voltage, resistors, voltage-regulator, dc

I've been struggling for a few weeks trying to find a way to lower the voltage coming out of my new solar panel array (35V DC, 36amps, 960watts).  I have an inverter that will not accept voltage over 30volts.

I've been looking at resistors, voltage regulators..etc  but very few options for that wattage.  I also tried puttting a load in parrallel and series on the circuit..no luck

I did manage to find a 1000w 25ohm resistor on Ebay, but I can't seem to calculate the outcomes with any accuracy.

NEW**  Would a 30V 40amp Rectifier Diode work???

Comment: A resistor won't work, you'll kill the inverter with it sooner or later. On the other hand, the only viable solution is to buy an inverter with the correct input specs. Any viable other solution basically means building an in-between inverter. Bring your inverter back to the shop or sell it on eBay while it still works and is in good condition, use the money for a new one.

Comment: It might be easier to look at the inverter circuit and make changes to it rather than trying to design a fairly efficient buck converter. (or do the above)

Comment: @jippie Or maybe the solar panel array supports an internal reconfiguration, not to stack so many cells in series?

Comment: @Kaz fair enough, I took the array as a given configuration and did not consider rearranging it.

Comment: You could use the voltage drop from diodes in series. 50A diodes are not that [expensive](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/FFH50US60S/FFH50US60SFS-ND/1057811). However voltage drop is [variable](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/ds/FF/FFH50US60S.pdf) depending on current (and to a lesser degree, diode temperature), for this one, ranging from around 0.75V per diode @ 10A to 1.25V @50A, but that might work out for you if you want to drop less voltage with lower current. You'll need good heatsinks, 1.25V@30A is about 40W of (wasted) power to dissapate. But the previous solutions are better.

Comment: Take a look at: http://www.absopulse.com/Absopulse_PressRel_BAP_1K-U7712_Jan_2012.php

Answer (score 1):

It would be a shame to just waste 180W (5V X 36A), nearly 20% of the array power output, with a resistor (or a diode, linear regulator, etc.).

I suspect you have invested a significant sum in a solar array (far more than the inverter, correct?) with that much capability *so don't waste it!*

As comments have pointed out, reconfigure the array to produce less voltage with more current, replace the inverter or, if replacing or modifying the inverter is not an option and you don't want to throw away 20% of your array's output, you could look into a switching DC to DC converter to reduce the 35V array output to something your inverter can tolerate while wasting far less array power.

Comment: Thank you for all the great input.  The problem was my ignorance with the panels The stated voltage (under load) and the actual voltage while open was not considered. The inverters can handle the stated voltage but never get there because the starting / open voltage is too high. Most inverters unless I get into higher cost will have similar limitations on voltage. It is an option I have considered to sell and buy different.  I will look at the diode and DC-DC converter options.    Once the inverts start, the voltage should drop (specs of panels) but to late, diodes consuming watts.

Comment: @RandyMcAllister, in that case, all you might need is a "soft start" circuit that limits the initial applied voltage to the inverter until it is up and running and then switches out of the path.

Answer (score 0):

I'm certainly no expert in solar panels (living in England) but it strikes me that if you had some sort of circuit that monitored the panel's output voltage and used this to rotate (or obscure) the solar panel slightly in (or out) of the suns direct rays you can regulate the voltage.

Certain protection methods would be needed to ensure you couldn't get more than 30V (by maybe open circuiting the solar panel circuit).

It's all a bit "magnets and mirrors" really with hopefully no smoke.

Answer (score 0):

a crude fixed duty (say... 75%) buck convert should be suitable. shouldn't waste too much, compared to a diode OR make the other part 35V tolerant

Comment: 75% is less than 83% = 1 - 6V/36V (diode solution)

Comment: @Curd - A buck converter CONVERTS energy - the 75% is the ratio on Vout/Vin. The available current will increase. Efficiency is not 100%, but well ver 90% conversion efficincy is easily enough achieved.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon: I know that a buck converter CONVERTS energy. I assumed Naib is talking about 75% efficiency.

Comment: @Curd - OK - we are 'all on the same page thenm. No, rearranging his words he is saying "a fixed 75% duty-cycle buck converter..." . ie it is on 75% of the time and off 25% of the time. If you run this in continuous mode and filter the output you get Vout = 75% x Vin. So if eg the panel was at 36V the output would be about 36V x 75% = 27V. If you run at fixed duty cycles Vout will drop to ~ Vin x duty_cycle x efficiency. eg if efficiency was 90% and DC=75% at Vin = 40V you get ~= 40V x 75% x 90% = 27V

Comment: @Curd no I was not referring to efficiency. As stated in my comment **DUTY**. A duty of 75% (or 80%, 90%... was a throwaway markspace ratio before detail design) should provide what the OP wants if he cannot source parts > 35V.  Had I be referring to efficiency rest assured I would have written **efficiency**

Answer (score 0):

The panels are presumably nominally 24V rated.
A 24V panels has 72 cells and makes about 36 Voc (open circuit, no load).
Depending on the efficiency of the cells the loaded voltage will usually be about 80%-85% of open circuit or about 30V give or take a small amount. As you load the panels the voltage will drop as current increases and much more rapidly as peak current point is approached.

If you add a temporary switchable load to the panels when they are not loaded by the inverter you can reduce the voltage enough to allow the inverter to start. This can be done with eg a voltage sensor (essentially a comparator) driving a switch (probably a MOSFET, could be a bipolar transistor, could even be a relay) which adds a load.
For a load you can probably use a suitably rated light bulb or several bulbs.
Using say 3 x 12V bulbs in series provides a load that is rated at 36V but which will still draw significant % of its rated power as voltage decreases.
The long thin envelope "festoon bulbs"used in tail lights and similar in older cars often have straighter and more rugged filaments than round bulb glass bulbs.

If you use a resistor, the resistance R to dissipate a given power P at Voltage V is given by
R = V^2/P
So for say 1000W at 30V you need 30^2/1000 = 0.9 Ohm
so the 250 Ohm resistor would be much too high.
To dissipate 100W - possibly enough to load the panel down for startup - you need a 9 Ohm resistor.

An easy test to get you going is to take 3 x 12V bulbs rated at say 50W each, wire them in series and use them to load the panel in full sunlight. The voltage drop that they produce will show you what order of load is going to be needed.

The above mentioned startup load switch should be an on/off device if it is not to dissipate too much energy in the actual switch. This will initially load the panel down, the inverter will start and take up the load, the panel voltage will drop and the comparator will remove the starting load. The panel voltage will now TRY and step increase and it is up to the abilities of the controller as to whether it will be able to handle the step power change. A softer changeover can be designed if necessary.

---

**Heath Robinson solution:**

Place a piece of white gauze material or similar opartial light blocker over all or some cells to reduce max power.
Start inverter.
Remove cover.
This may not reduce voltage by enough at zero load.

If you shade one cell almost completely most panel's will drop output to near zero.
Some panels have internal bypass diodes which stop this reduction.
In systems with multiple panels chained to provide a high voltage (100V+ usually) shading one cell will place voltage stress on other cells and can cause cell breakdown and fire in a faulty cell. This is almost certainly not going to happen in a 30V system.

Comment: Thanks all, this is great education for me. My experience has been in House Wiring, not DC nor curcuits. I'm looking for Diodes, Resistors and Regulators/Rectifiers. I found the following and would appreciate your thoughts on if this will work before I proceed.  Schottky Diodes & Rectifiers part # 844-43CTT100 

http://ca.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Vishay/VS-43CTT100/?qs=%2fha2pyFadui8CWzsJvjolbetJKX0FvdThUa6lgSRuY8%3d

Comment: @RandyMcAllister I do not know how you intend to use a diode in this application. It is unlikely that a diode will do much good by itself. The one shown will (just) handle system current by itself but dissipates around 40 Watts doing so.  Would need a substantial heatsink- AND how would you use this. | Try my lightbulbs load manually. Report back.